# Array elements are corrupted by lazyness

Tags: ruby, dictionary

Why do we see such difference below? Why exactly such array?

```
enum = [1,2].lazy.flat_map{[[3,4],[5,6]]}.with_index

enum.to_a.map(&:first)
# => [[3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

enum.map(&:first).to_a
# => [[], [5], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: @sawa DRY... Humm ? :-)

Comment: I know.. I was joking..

Comment: Same thing happens without `lazy`...

Comment: @sawa - replace `with_index` with `each_with_index`...

Comment: @UriAgassi I got it. In other words, the question can be simplified to having `enum = [[3,4], [5,6], [3,4], [5,6]].each_with_index`.

Comment: You should consider a Ruby bug ticket to the Core team.. It is odd behavior..Try `[[3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6]].each_with_index.map(&:first)` , `[[3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6]].each_with_index.map{ |*x| x.first }` and `[[3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6]].each_with_index.map{ |x| x.first }`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Which one is odd to you?

Comment: @sawa In my example first and last..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens has nothing to do with `lazy` - it has something to do with the subtleties of `map(&:...)`.

The first option (`enum.to_a.map(&:first)`) translates to:

```
enum.to_a.map { |x| x.first }
# => [[3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

when `x` is `[[3,4], 0]`, then `[[5,6], 1]`...

The second option, one the other hand translates to:

```
enum.map { |x, i| x.first(i) } 
# => [[], [5], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

which brings the first `i` item for each `x` array (since the arrays in our example have only 2 elements, `x.first(3)` still returns two elements...).

The same would happen without `lazy`:

```
enum2 = [1,2].flat_map{[[3,4],[5,6]]}.to_enum.with_index
```

What `to_a` does in this case is takes the two parameters of each item in the enumeration, and turns them to a single array item.

Comment: `[1,2].flat_map{[[3,4],[5,6]]}` can actually be simplified to `[[3,4], [5,6], [3,4], [5,6]]`.

Comment: It will be clearer if you mention that, in the second option, since each `x` only has two elements, `x.first(3)` can only take two elements.

Comment: Cool, now I know one more type of hacks: `5.times.zip.each.with_index.map(&:*)`

Comment: It may be explained why are *the subtleties* … `&:first` passed to a method converts symbol `:first` to a `Proc` with `Symbol#to_proc` and passes to `map` as a block argument. The resulting method of `Symbol#to_proc` *takes arbitrary number of arguments*, in this example equivalent to `proc {|*args| args.first.send(:first, args.drop(1)) }`. In other words symbol as the method name is sent to the first argument, rest of arguments are sent as additional arguments to this method.